# sql query to check many interests are matched

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am building a swingers site. The users can search other users by their interests. This is only part of a number of parameters used to search a user. The thing is there are like 100 different interests. When searching another user they can select all the interests the user must share. While I can think of ways to do this, I know it is important the search be as efficient as possible.
The backend uses jdbc to connect to a mysql database. Java is the backend programming language.
I have debated using multiple columns for interests but generating the thing is the sql query need not check them all if those columns are not addressed in the json object send to the server telling it the search criteria. Also I worry i may have to make painful modifications to the table at a later point if i add new columns.

Another thing I thought about was having some kind of long byte array, or number (used like a byte array) stored in a single column. I could & this with another number corresponding to the interests the user is searching for but I read somewhere this is actually quite inefficient despite it making good sense to my mind :/

And all of this has to be part of one big sql query with multiple tables joined into it.

One of the issues with me using multiple columns would be the compiting power used to run statement.setBoolean on what could be 40 columns.
I thought about generating an xml string in the client then processing that in the sql query.

Any suggestions?

I think the correct term is a Bitmask. I could maybe have one table for the bitmask that maps the users id to the bitmask for querying users interests, and another with multiple entries for each interest per user id for looking up which user has which interests efficiently if I later require this?

Comment: "multiple columns for interests" is usually a bad idea.

Comment: you can use a separate table for keeping interests. it would be simple enough to maintain. bitmap might be an issue since the space required would increase based on 2^(no of interests) which is not recommended

Comment: You may want to read up on one-to-many- and many-to-many - relations and the strategies to handle them.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it would be great to have a separate table with all the interests, 2 columns: `id` and `interest`.

Then, have a table that links the user to the interests: `user_interests` which would have the following columns: `id`,`user_id`,`interest_id`. Here some knowledge about many-to-many relations would help a lot.

Hope it helps!

Comment: also, when finding a solution, you should try to close the question